# Consulta Eloquent en tres tablas

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relaciones

Buenas tardes necesito hacer una consulta en laravel pero los resultados no son los que espero, ojalá alguien me pueda ayudar.

[image: Estas son mis tablas:]
Estas son mis tablas:

Y estos son los resultados que deseo obtener: que la MARCA se imprima una sola vez y seguidamente la lista de los productos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La relaciones son las siguientes:

```
class Marca extends Model {   
public function productos()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Producto::class,'idmarca');
}}
-----------------
class Producto extends Model
public function categoria()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Categoria::class,'idcategoria');
}

public function marca()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Marca::class,'idmarca');
}

-----------------
class Categoria extends Model
{

public function productos()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Producto::class,'idcategoria');
}
```

Comment: puedes agregar el contenido que haz intentado? así como si estas trabajando con los métodos belongs to y has many de laravel o estas escribiendo tus joins por cuenta propia; por que para ayudarte tus imágenes no nos ayudan

Comment: Ya lo edité con las relaciones

Answer (score 0):

lo mejor es meter el codigo sql en el poblemas, no le puedo ayudar de mucho

en la consulta lo esta haciendo de la siguiente manera

```
$consulta = Producto::with('categoria_pk','Marca_pk')->get();
```

y en el modelo realizalo de la siguiente manera

```
class Producto extends Model
public function categoria_pk()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Categoria','idcategoria');
}

public function marca_pk()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Marca','idmarca');
}
```

en la parte de **idcategoria** y **idmarca** corresponde a la llave foránea si tiene poblema de visualizar los datos en la view coloque **var_dump($datos)**